# How can i find files containing multiple patterns

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

I have many files  within folders and subfolders.
I have file called `patterns.txt` which contains patterns per line.
Now i want o find files which match all those patterns. Patterns can be in any order.

Example

patterns.txt

```
userdata
"/"
"{a: 1}"
```

My files are json example

```
"userdata": ""
"dir": "/"
"mdict": {a: 1}
```

I am able to find single pattern or max two patterns but not multiple like below

```
find /logs/ -name "*.json" -exec  grep -rni 'userdata' /dev/null {} \; | cut -d":" -f1 | grep -rni '"/"'
```

is it possible to get patterns from file and match all of them?

Comment: so in your case there should not be any output, cause the 3rd pattern `"{a: 1}"` won't match

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need `egrep` or `grep -E` for GNU grep(only `OR`):

```
$ egrep -nri "userdata|dir|..."
$ grep -nriE "userdata|dir|..."
```

if you want to match multiple lines using `AND`:

```
$ find /logs/ -name "*.json" |xargs grep -izl "$(cat patterns.txt |tr '\n' 'x' |sed 's/x/.*/g')"
```

> -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
>
> -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches

Comment: that wlll only do OR , i want to do AND